# topics of inference conditional probability question

Tags: probability

I am learning topics of inference.
I have learned when

> $$P(∣)=\frac{P(∩)}{P()}=\frac{P(A)\times P(B)}{P(B)}$$

but why sometimes the solution works like this?

> $$ P(∣)=\frac{P(∩)}{P()}=\frac{P()}{P()}$$

I really want to know what is the difference between two.

Answer (score 0):

$P(A\cap B)$ isnot generally $P(A)\times P(B)$. That relation $P(A\cap B)=P(A)\times P(B)$ is only true if $A$ and $B$ are independent events, i.e. whether the event $B$ has happened or not, does not affect the probability of event $A$ occuring, or, in other words, $P(A|B)=P(A)$.

Also $P(A\cap B)=P(A)$ only if $P(A\setminus B)=0$ (as for two disjoint sets $C$ and $D$, $P(C)+P(D)=P(C\sqcup D)$).